# How to include .d.ts file manually(locally)? Or How to use a user defined .d.ts file?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm studying nuxt.js and due to some reason I want to extend Vue's instance like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.prototype.$myProp = 'test'

const app = new Vue()

console.log(app.$myProp)
```

Following the guide at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins, I have create a file at types/test.d.ts with the content bellow:

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $myProp: string;
  }
}
```

However, I don't know how to make it works.

I was receiving errors in my VSCode. Also receive errors when I executing tsc(Version 3.7.2):

```
index.ts:14:17 - error TS2339: Property '$test' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, object, object, object, Record<never, any>>'.

14 console.log(app.$test)
```

I have tried to using a tsconfig.json in the root directory, but not work:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": [
            "types/test.d.ts"
        ]
    }
}
```

I have also tried insert a reference like this, but now work:

```
///<reference path="types/test.d.ts"/>
```

Of course, I don't want to include this declare file in every file. Is there a way to enable the declare in whole project?

I don't know how VSCode works with typescript. Maybe I just make a mistake in config file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`typeRoots` refers to directories, not files. Plus, it refers to the containing folder of *types packages*.

> A types package is a folder with a file called index.d.ts or a folder with a package.json that has a types field. - [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)

Typically this is the `./node_modules/@types` folder, which is also the default value of `typeRoots` option.

For your case, it's better to use the `include` option instead of `typeRoots`.

```
{
  "include": [
    "./types",
    /* other .ts or .d.ts source code containing folders here */
  ],
  "compilerOptions": { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works when I executing `tsc -p tsconfig.json`. But the editor still shows an error when I attempt to access the property I added. Maybe I have made another mistake in my VSCode config but I don't know how to fix it. This is my first question on stack overflow and I don't know how to use it correctly. Should I open a new question?

Comment: Just run "Restart TS Server" command inside vscode, or try quit and restart vscode might fix it. I encounter this problem quite alot.

Comment: I have try run "Restart TS Server" command and restart vscode. But it doesn't work. Even stranger, it works in another workspace. I don't know how.

Comment: Probably sth wrong in your local config? Try start a new project to pinpoint the problem. Not much I can do from here. Perhaps you put your tsconfig in wrong place, perhaps your vscode's ts setting is picking up wrong tsconfig file. But i'm pretty sure this solution works.